# Redmine bug in Chrome

Tags: redmine, bug-tracker

I'm working with Redmine for a long time already. From time to time my our team detects some bugs in it, like this one on the image below. It appears on My Page in Chrome only. I haven't found an answer in Redmine forum. Has anyone run into such a bug as well? Any ideas, what caused the problem and how to fix it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmZpR.png

Also, I’m interested in alternatives to Redmine. What trackers do you prefer and why? I’d be glad to see any information on comparison of Redmine analogues. Thanks.

Comment: I guess, Redmine [bugtracker page](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues) - is the better place for it's bug reports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is just a bug in **CSS**, **Redmine** is OpenSource you can fix it by yourself, just see the source myPage view. [This](http://www.redmine.org/issues/3438) can help.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed my problem. What do you think about other issue and bug trackers, like Mantis and others? Are they worth trying instead of Redmine, which I think is not quite user-friendly?

Comment: I don't know others. Redmine meets my needs.